# predicted value does not change

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am working with neural network and use Keras. 
Just to explain my problem:
[predicted and real data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV6NN.png)

Creation of model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(
         input_shape=(sequence_length, nb_features),
         units=100,
         return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(LSTM(
          units=50,
          return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.add(Activation("linear"))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae', r2_keras])
```

Fit function:

```
history = model.fit(seq, label_array, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.2, verbose=2,
          callbacks = [#keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=10, verbose=0, mode='min'),
                       keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(model_path, monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True, mode='min', verbose=0)]
          )
```

I know that is difficult to say where exactly the error is, but maybe there is something simple that could explain why predicted value is always the same. 
P.S Input data! At first I use `pd.DataFrame(min_max_scaler.fit_transform(array_x))`, after `generate_sequences(array_x)` and finally `estimator.predict(np.array(array_x))`.

Comment: Can you detail how you are transforming the input data? That's probably where I would start.

Comment: @ChrisFarr just added it to the post